# Add user to Linux command

Tags: linux, command-line

I try to write c program program to add user in Linux this is my code

```
char a[50];
char command[150];
printf("Please enter username \n");
fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
strcpy(command,"useradd ");
strcat(command,a);
system(command);
```

but this code can't run correctly when i use it the shell show the `man command` help for `useradd`
how i use this command correctly to add user using c ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but `a` is the name of user?
you need to assign in what group the user will be add:

```
useradd -G groupname username
```

try:

```
strcpy(command,"useradd -G <groupname>");
```